# Wordpress gallery ignoring shortcode

Tags: wordpress, gallery

I am trying to use a gallery to display 3 Images in a grid in the same line and same size and want the images to link to other sites when clicked.

I am using the "**WP Gallery Custom Links**" addon and Juno as my theme.

My problem is, that the gallery doesn't change the sizes of the images.
In fact the gallery ignores any kind of shortcode other than the images that it should display. I tried deactivating all plugins and using the standard-theme, as well as resizing the thumbnail images and even the images themself.

The following call is used:

```
[gallery size="150x150" columns="3" ids="1264,1257,1280"]
```

So i even changed the local files to have 150x150 size and the gallery is now scaling them up to 596x189 px.

```
<img src="..." style="width: 596px; height: 189px;" alt="">
```

I also changed the options for the standart sizes in the media-options to 150x150 in all sizes.
Also the pictures are not displayed in one line, but instead two in the top and one in another row, even thougth i am using 3 columns.

So if someone can help me, i probably just dont see something, but i dont know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i found the error, i added

```
.gallery figure.gallery-item {
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

to the custom-css, seems the width in the gallery-item, that was wrapping the images did scale them down.
If someone knows where i can change this parameter in the options, or if there is a way to do so without the custom clause then please answer in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

See [size attribute docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode#Options). Instead of specifying exact dimensions, specify a named size in WordPress core, or a named size that is added by your theme or other plugins.

> size  specify the image size to use for the thumbnail display. Valid
>   values include "thumbnail", "medium", "large", "full" and any other
>   additional image size that was registered with add_image_size(). The
>   default value is "thumbnail". The size of the images for "thumbnail",
>   "medium" and "large" can be configured in WordPress admin panel under
>   Settings > Media. For example, to display a gallery of medium sized
>   images:

Comment: i already set all sizes to 150x150 just to see if it works, also tried using medium and large as parameters. sadly it didnt change anything